# Canvas получается разного размера на разных устройствах

Tags: html, html5, canvas, chart.js

Я рисую на canvas график с помощью Chart.js, потом копирую этот канвас на другой, добавляю описание и итоговый вариант добавляю в PDF.

Проблема в том, что на телефоне (Android 6, Chrome) и на ПК (Win7, Chrome) canvas'ы выглядят по разному.

Вот так он должен выглядит на ПК:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так на телефоне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. на телефоне, почему то, график отрисовывается на бОльшем канвасе, чем на ПК. Или же он растягивается, не знаю.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Update:**

```
var pageWidth = 1122; //2339; // 842
var pageHeight = 793; //1654; // 545

// Document
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');

// Render
var renderDiv = document.createElement('div');
renderDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
renderDiv.style.top = '-1000px';
renderDiv.style.left = '-1000px';
renderDiv.style.width = px(pageWidth);
//renderDiv.style.maxWidth = px(pageWidth);

var chartCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
console.log(chartCanvas);
renderDiv.appendChild(chartCanvas);
document.body.appendChild(renderDiv);

// Page
var pageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
pageCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
pageCanvas.style.top = '-1000px';
pageCanvas.style.left = '-1000px';
pageCanvas.width = pageWidth;
pageCanvas.height = pageHeight;
//pageCanvas.style.maxWidth = px(pageWidth);
document.body.appendChild(pageCanvas);

///console.log(renderDiv);
//console.log(pageCanvas);

function px(number) {
    return number + 'px';
}

function clearCanvas(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawFirstPage() {
    var ctx = pageCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#507299";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);                

    var x = pageWidth / 2;
    var y = pageHeight / 2;
    var lineHeight = 40;

    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

    ctx.font = px(38) + " RobotoRegular";
    ctx.fillText('', x, y - lineHeight / 2);

    ctx.font = px(16) + " RobotoRegular";
    ctx.fillText('Комплексный отчет по активности сообществ', x, y + lineHeight / 2);

    ctx.textAlign = "left";

    doc.addImage(pageCanvas, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    doc.addPage();
}

function drawBackground() {
    var ctx = pageCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#EDEEF0";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
}

function drawChart(chartObject) {
    clearCanvas(chartCanvas);
    var chart = new Chart(chartCanvas, chartObject);
    var destCtx = pageCanvas.getContext('2d');
    destCtx.drawImage(chartCanvas, 0, 0);
    chart.destroy();
}

function drawDescription(chartObject) {

    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
        var words = text.split(' ');
        var line = '';
        for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
            var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
            var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
            var testWidth = metrics.width;
            if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
                context.fillText(line, x, y);
                line = words[n] + ' ';
                y += lineHeight;
            } else {
                line = testLine;
            }
        }
        context.fillText(line, x, y);
    }

    var ctx = pageCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#507299";

    var x = 0, y = pageWidth / 2, w = pageWidth, h = pageHeight - y;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';

    var headerFontSize = Math.floor(pageHeight / 19);
    var descriptionFontSize = Math.floor(pageHeight / 34);
    var descriptionOffset = Math.floor(headerFontSize * 1.4);
    var textPadding = Math.floor(headerFontSize / 5.6);

    ctx.font = px(headerFontSize) + " RobotoRegular";
    ctx.fillText(chartObject.settings.name, x + textPadding, y);

    ctx.font = px(descriptionFontSize) + " RobotoRegular";
    wrapText(ctx, chartObject.settings.descr, x + textPadding, y + descriptionOffset, pageWidth - textPadding, headerFontSize);
}

function drawStatisticsPage(chart, addPage) {
    clearCanvas(pageCanvas);
    drawBackground(pageCanvas);
    drawChart(chart, pageCanvas);
    drawDescription(chart, pageCanvas);

    doc.addImage(pageCanvas, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    if (addPage) {
        doc.addPage();
    }
}

drawFirstPage();

var keys = Object.keys(self.charts);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    drawStatisticsPage(self.charts[keys[i]], i != keys.length - 1);
}

document.body.removeChild(renderDiv);
document.body.removeChild(pageCanvas);

doc.save('report.pdf');
```

Comment: viewport стоит для мобилок?

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко, на сколько я понимаю, да, стоят, т.к. я использую Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Выведи див в 300px под графиком с background-color, посмотри как он будет себя вести

Comment: @ДмитрийПриходченко, хм... Он очень сильно меняется в размерах, почти в два раза. Но можно ли ему запретить это?

Answer (score 0):

Поставь viewpost (вставляет внутрь тега )

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Это задаст начальное увеличение 1, те увеличиваться по идее ничего не должно.

Comment: Не помогает. Я уже кучу разных вариантов настройки вьюпорта пробовал, сама страница меняет свое отображение, а канвас как был растянутый, так таким и оставался.

Comment: Ты не вставлял div с бекграундом? по нему можно было бы понять, правильно ли ведут себя блоки или все таки растягиваются

Comment: Проблема может быть еще в том, что у твоего канваса нету обертки, из за этого он позволяет себе растягиваться. Попробуй еще обернуть его в див с ограниченной шириной

Comment: Канвас обернут в див, да. Я даже пробовал задавать ему максимальную ширину, но это не помогло.

Comment: Скинь хоть код анициализации, мб в нем ошибка. Безысходность

Comment: Я прикрепил в первом сообщении код с помощью которого генерируются канвасы. Хз, может в нем проблема.